# Can iPhone connect to Mac or another iPhone through Bluetooth Classic ( not BLE )

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth

I want to create a simulator to test the connection between the accessory ( which is already registered for MFi ) and my App. Currently, I'm using Bluetooth Classic. I have researched a lot but there's no answer and the document from Apple doesn't say that it can be done or not. Anyone have any solutions ?
Thank you.

Comment: With Bluetooth Classic you mean BR/EDR? If yes, it should be possible. I'd recommend to check the [WWDC 2019 - 901 - What's New in Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901) session. You can either watch it or check the slides/download sample app. But I'm not a BT expert and I can be wrong,  I just remember watching this session.

Comment: No, i tried this one already. It doesn't work. With BLE i'm sure that i can do it